# How can I solve the blurring problem in GAN generated images?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-networks, image-processing, cycle-gan

In my project I work in dresses dataset. I can solve the problem of black pixels but blurring still existed. I tried many computer vision filters like median filter, Biliteral filter, Sharpen methods and more.
But none of them could help me. Hope to find solutions in Deep learning, machine learning or image processing Techniques. [image: This is one of samples which I want to enhance]

Comment: It might not so much be blurring but that no edges are generated. That may be due to the generating network producing smooth functions by construction or by training. Is the image representative? If yes, a higher resolution might be required.

Comment: Yes, I need more resolution as it's important that the image is clear enough.